# Tensorflow "Hello World" example does not work in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow

I entered these code in PyCharm and included Tensorflow in interpreter:

```
import tensorflow
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

However the terminal didn't print anything and output was "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are refering to `tf` in your code, therefore you have to `import tensorflow as tf`.

In addition you should rename your filename. For example change `tf.py` to `main.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `import tensorflow` with `import tensorflow as tf`, also it is probably good to rename your script other than tf.py.